# How do I turn off permalinks only for *tags* in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url, tags, permalinks

Is there any way to turn off "permalinks" only for *tags* in WordPress?
I'd like to keep the `?tag=` structure and have the tags displayed without slashes, but also keep post and page URLs with nice permalinks.

For example: 
With permalinks on I'd like to have tag linked like this: `?tag=carrot` instead of `/tag/carrot/`

The reason for doing this is a bit long and complicated, but if you think it is relevant, I might include it in the replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `term_link` filter in WordPress, which filters the URL for any of the term links (tags, categories, custom taxonomies) to just change the links for tags to use the query instead of the permalinks. Adding the following to a plugin or your theme's `functions.php` file should do the trick.

```
function filter_tag_link($taglink, $tag, $taxonomy) {
    if ('post_tag' == $taxonomy) {
        $taglink = '?tag='.$tag->slug;
    }  
    return $taglink;
}

add_filter('term_link', 'filter_tag_link', 10, 3);
```

There is no useful documentation yet for `term_link` filter on the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Link_Filters), but [looking at the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2980) may help if you want to explore further.